# Why should I ever go green?

Tags: penny-arcade-gamers-vs-evil

My friends an I have tried playing this game a few times now and have come to the conclusion that going a green never wins. Green cards do not seem to be more powerful than red cards and yet red cards have victory points attached to them. This gives players who go red an automatic advantage over those who go green. Going balanced doesn't seem to work well either since then you do not have the power or token generation to get boss loots.

So the question is why would you ever go green, or more exactly why would you ever not go red?

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the setup. If you've got Bat Milk, and a few other deck thinners, you remove all of the other trash from you deck, draw your entire deck every turn, and win before anyone else has really started.

Green has the majority of the deck thinning cards (and PVP Defense). Also most of your combo cards are going to be in green. Werewolf in a Tophat and 3 Natural 20s = 3 of each boss loot all on the same turn. With Bat Milk in the mix you can do that reliably.

On the other hand, sometimes Red IS the better choice. Again it depends on the setup, and how other people play. Having some Defense or Deck Thinning is vital if you have a lot of people buying PVP attacks.

Answer (score 1):

The real question is why bother to focus on one side at all? There are plenty of cards on both sides that increase the power of the other side. As for you claim that Red cards are more powerful I would argue that green cards are more powerful.

Depending on what cards are available a green deck has lot of power and its all in how the cards are used.

Baby Ninja: While it adds +1 power its great to have for pvp defense (and you get a replacement card) and it can be used with other green cards

Magical Unicorn: Great for getting rid of a bad hand.

Bat Milk: Doesn't give much by itself but it can be used to get a replacement card that is more valuable and it can clean your deck of red cards if you are going pure green.

Robot Cowboy Angel: Great pvp defense as you get 2 cards back and if not needed for pvp defence you can just draw another card in its place.

Faerie Candymancer: Great for removing pox cards since you can draw another card and it can get rid of red cards.

Psychic Cat, Stone Yeti and Hawkman with a Laser Gun: Great card for early on where you can discard a quarter and a cardboard tube to get 3 Tokens.

TochWieners: Free card if your opponents also get them

Natural Twenty: One of the most powerful cards in the game once you start using two of them since they are cumulative in power. Throw two of them on a Werewolf with a Top Hat and you got a total of 12 tokens and 12 power for 3 cards which shows you how quickly they can give you tokens/power. That combo can allow you to buy both red and green boss cards while not worrying about other red cards.

Sorcelator: How can you go wrong with 1 token, 1 power and 1 card?

Pickle Recognition Engine: In a green deck this will give you 5 tokens most of the time and combine it with a few Natural Twenty's and you will soon have the ability to buy multiple boss cards on a turn.

Werewolf with a Top Hat: 3 tokens and 3 power combined with Natural Twenty is a great way to build up green cards and grab red boss loots before your opponent.

Sure the only green cards with victory points are the boss loots but the cards have the ability to help a player build up quickly.

In the end the decision to go with pure green, pure red or a combination of the two really depends on what what cards are available for the game. Nothing is set in stone when you can get a game with 9 or 10 stacks of green cards then it would be silly to worry to much about red if they didn't have many cards that help you get the boss loot quickly.

Comment: The problem is, going green your high end points you can get is 63 (maybe a little more if you grabbed a few low cost red cards). This can also only occur if you got all green boss loots, which probably wont happen. This number is pitiful compared to what red decks can generate.

Comment: For example, my roommates and I did a run where we completely stacked the green side to give it the best advantage possible (using several of the cards you listed above). We also put the worst cards we could on the red side. Then we had 2 players go red (thus competing for points) and one go green. Even with all of this in his favor the green guy still got crushed.

Comment: But you are missing the point, it is very possible to buy only green cards but still be able to buy red boss loot. To me it sounds like the players who are going green are not playing to the best ability because with the right cards you can quickly buy out all the green boss cards and end the game preventing other players from building up many points.